# How to create upper sheet in jetpack compose for android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

As in the title, I have a problem with creating upper sheet - equivalent to ModalBottomSheet, which upens from the top to bottom.

I tried to achieve it by putting ModalBottomSheet into a Box with Modifier.graphicsLayer(rotationZ = 180f) which had to rotate the whole content of the Box by 180 degrees, however it did not work.

Here's the code with my idea:

```
package com.example.m3b

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.graphicsLayer
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.m3b.ui.theme.*

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            Column(

                Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color(Timberwolf.value)),

                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top

            ) {

                val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
                var sheetIsOpened by remember {

                    mutableStateOf(false)

                }

                Button(

                    onClick = { sheetIsOpened = true }

                ) {


                }

                if (sheetIsOpened) {

                    Box( // intention of this box was to rotate the whole content by 180 degrees

                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .graphicsLayer(rotationZ = 180f)

                    ) {

                        ModalBottomSheet(

                            onDismissRequest = { sheetIsOpened = false }, sheetState = sheetState,

                            modifier = Modifier.height(500.dp)


                        ) {


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```